# Is there a way to merge a list of dicts into a single dict using glom library?

Tags: python, glom

I'm using [glom](https://github.com/mahmoud/glom) project.

Is there a way to convert `[{"id": 1, "name": "foo"}, {"id": 2, "name": "bar"}]` to `{1: "foo", 2: "bar"}`?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. That question is completely different from the one asked here. @ConstantinGuidon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

New `glom` version (19.2.0) allows to use `Merge` to merge two dicts.

```
from glom import glom, T, Merge

target = [{"id": 1, "name": "foo"}, {"id": 2, "name": "bar"}]
spec = Merge([{T["id"]: T["name"]}])

glom(target, spec)
# {1: 'foo', 2: 'bar'}
```

Docs: https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=merge#glom.Merge